# Salesforce System Down without warning messages

Tags: bug

We noticed that Salesforce instance is not available and when log in it's asking to check the availability at http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/. This is the first time I had this experience which salesforce did this without sending any early warning mails. After having a look at the given link I noticed that several instances are facing the same or similar situations. Those are because of **Performance Degradation, Service disruption, etc.** 
Has anyone experienced this before? I'm confusing about the reliability of Salesforce, because I believe customer is the king concept :)

Thanks,
Madhura

Comment: Yes.. Today 30/june I faced the same Issues both in Enterprise and Developer Edition in AP1 Instance.

Answer (score 2):

Its happened to me before on at least one of the orgs I was working in. Its relatively rare and you can bet that SF is working their rearends off to fix the problems they're having; especially if it requires rebuilding instances that are totally down. Generally though, these things are short-lived occurrences.

Whenever your instance seems to be running slow or other things don't seem to be working as they should be, that's always good time to check the status link to see if there are any known problems with your instance. Compared to running your own server, I think SF is far more reliable in terms of up time, but don't have any figures at hand to support that assertion.

Answer (score 0):

It is an ideal way to direct customer's to Trust.salesforce.com website to check the status or it means salesforce is telling you that they are having performance issues.

If your company has a salesforce support team and if the performance is down, your internal support team will be flooded with cases/tickets.

In this case, Everybody who tries to perform a DML operation or login will see the above message.